# text view on the image view?

Tags: java, android, string

the text should be saved on the image view ?the text should not be defined in the layout folder and should be saved on the image view on the accordingly from the key board ?

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fullimage);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullimage);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    }

}
```

Comment: use a relative layout or framelayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use framelayout for that .. define both ImageView and TextView and set text on TextView

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thumbHolder">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:id="@+id/titletxt"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#80000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:text="" />


    </FrameLayout>
```

for setting custom font :-

1. create "assets\fonsts\"  folder and then place your font there
2. then create a typeface by loading that font :-

   Typeface tfBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Bold.otf");
3. then set your typeface in textView :-

   yourTextView.setTypeface(tfBold);

Comment: then how to save a text o the image with different fonts on the image ?

Comment: you can use different typefaces for that ... let me update my ans

Comment: then how to save a text on the image view automatically without drag and drop position?

Comment: check updated ans ... you just have to pass the value to setText() method.. and what do you mean by "without drag and drop position?" ?

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/image">


        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:text="text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the text should not be defined in the layout different users type their text in different ways they be displayed in the image view?

Comment: then set visibility off in layout using android:visibility="invisible" and programmatically make visible it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either draw the image on a canvas, and then draw the text on the image or else, create a layout via code and set the textview inside the layout and then place the layout on top of the image view with background of the textview set to transparent

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `TextView` only. Using `drawableTop`, `drawableBottom`, `drawableLeft`, `drawableRight` in the following way.

```
<TextView
    style="@style/layout_wrap"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/flags_00"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_tabs"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Team B" />
```

and in the code by the following way

```
battingTeamFlag.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Button and use button background to set image.and use text element for adding text on button.

```
   <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
     android:text="YourText"
     android:background="@drawable/image"
    >
   </Button>
```

According to your requirement you can get text from button and pass it with intent

Comment: can u help me with tutorial?